# How to show file chooser only if checkbox is checked?

Tags: html, file-upload, checkbox

I have a checkbox in HTML:

```
<div class="checkbox">
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox"> Want to choose another picture?
    </label>
  </div>
```

I also have a file chooser where user can choose and upload file:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="exampleInputFile">Choose main image</label>
    <input type="file" id="exampleInputFile">
    <p class="help-block">This will be your thumbnail image</p>
  </div>
```

**How do I only show the file chooser if the first checkbox has been checked?**

Thanks

Comment: If you want it in PHP, it will have to happen after the user submits the page. You probably want to actually do this in Javascript.

Comment: Yes, that makes sense as the file input should expand as soon as checkbox has been checked. Thanks for pointing that out... Updated question

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps

```
<div class="checkbox">
   <label>
     <input type="checkbox" id="chk"> Want to choose another picture?
   </label>
</div>

<div class="form-group" id="file-input" style="display:none;">
 <label for="exampleInputFile">Choose main image</label>
  <input type="file" id="exampleInputFile">
  <p class="help-block">This will be your thumbnail image</p>
</div>
<script>
document.getElementById('chk').onchange = function(){
   if(this.checked) {document.getElementById('file-input').style.display='block';
   //more js statements
   }
   else {document.getElementById('file-input').style.display='none';
   //more js statements
   }
}
</script>
```

Comment: How do you change the style of more than one element... e.g. `if(this.checked) 
document.getElementById('file-input').style.display='block';` when I try to add another statement after the first one it doesn't do anything

Comment: see my edited answer. actually curly braces {} are optional for only one line to execute after conditions